# How do you know if a differential equation has analytic solutions?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a an ODE of the form $0=M\left(x,\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}},\frac{d^{3}x}{dt^{3}}...\right)$, where M is a multivariate polynomial of finite order.

How do you know it has analytic solutions? or non- analytic solutions? or a combination of the two?

Where a solution is described as analytic if its expressible as a taylor series.

Comment: Give some examples.

Comment: Experience. You know what kind of solution it has, because you've done so many exercises that nothing can surprise you any more.

Comment: When saying "analytic", do you mean "analytic functions" (like in power series), or "solutions expressible through a closed formula involving only elementary functions"?

Comment: I've just updated the question to fix al of your problems. Could we reopen it?

Comment: IS there anything else people would suggest I change to enable it to be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is very generic. It highly depends on the structure of your ODE, like order, type of nonlinearities, structure of the inhomogeneous terms, etc.

Maybe you know that even system of first order equations(like the so-called Jerk Systems) can have chaotic behavior, and in that case saying anything about the solution is almost impossible.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to be less generic